# XML Error: Ill-formed at the Amazon Envelope XML level at (or near) line 1, column 1

Tags: php, xml, amazon-web-services

I am trying to upload OrderFulfillment on Amazon.com marketplace by using Amazon MWS (in php) but get an error "XML you submitted is ill-formed at the Amazon Envelope XML level at (or near) line 1, column 1".

However I uploaded the same XML to scratchpad(https://mws.amazonservices.com/scratchpad/index.html) but it's work.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<AmazonEnvelope xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="amzn-envelope.xsd">
    <Header>
        <DocumentVersion>1.02</DocumentVersion>
        <MerchantIdentifier>Smile Dental</MerchantIdentifier>
    </Header>
    <MessageType>OrderFulfillment</MessageType>
    <Message>
        <MessageID>1</MessageID>
        <OrderFulfillment>
            <AmazonOrderID>114-0160617-7201843</AmazonOrderID>
            <FulfillmentDate>2016-04-21T06:47:14Z</FulfillmentDate>
            <FulfillmentData>
                <CarrierName>USPS</CarrierName>
                <ShippingMethod>Standard</ShippingMethod>
                <ShipperTrackingNumber>LS802843289CN</ShipperTrackingNumber>
            </FulfillmentData>
            <Item>
                <AmazonOrderItemCode>06591453767866</AmazonOrderItemCode>
                <Quantity>2</Quantity>
            </Item>
        </OrderFulfillment>
    </Message>
</AmazonEnvelope>
```

I can't find wrong.

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: can you make sure the generated xml does not contain an extra space or carriage return as the first character of the file

Comment: Yes, i'm sure. I check my xml again.

Comment: @mojo: did you get the solution? I'm facing the same issue,